# Will Masuda method work with Pokemon from different regions but same English name?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

Hunting for a Shiny Sentret/Furret and I'm doing the Masuda Method on Pokemon Ultra Moon.
I have a Spanish Furret and an Australian Ditto ready to breed for the Masuda method.

Even though the Spanish Furret's name is the same as its English name, will the Masuda method still work? It does have the "SPA" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method):

> The Masuda method involves breeding **two Pokémon created in games of different languages**.

So the current Pokemon's name is not important.

You're worring for no reason, since the Spanish name for Furret is the same as the English one, as you can see here (courtesy of [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Furret_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#In_other_languages), again):

[image]

So *Australian* Ditto + *Spanish* Furret can definitely use Masuda method.